# Type UNUserNotificationCenter has no member current, swift 2.3

Tags: notifications, swift2, ios10

In iOS10 User notifications were reworked by apple. 
Now I am trying to adjust my app to these changes, following [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/ios10):

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
```

gives me an error:

```
Type UNUserNotificationCenter has no member current, swift 2.3
```

I know that that tutorial is maybe for swift3. But I need to make it work in swift 2.3. Is it even feasible and if yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation seems in conflict with itself.  Although it describes the `current()` method and says to use it, the examples show `let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()`.

As you say, this may be a Swift version dependency.

Comment: can you post a link to those examples, because now i'm stuck a bit further, for probably same reasons?

Comment: @Async- On-line documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter

Answer (score 7):

for Xcode 8 / ios9/10

simply use:

```
import  UserNotifications
```

.
.

```
    // swift 3.0:
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
        }

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

// NOTE: if are in FOREGROUND, You will NEVER be called! :)

Comment: This was best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Import this:

```
import  UserNotifications
```

implement this delegate with in your `appDelegate` file:

```
UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
```

Which will give you access to the following methods:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, openSettingsFor notification: UNNotification?) {}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {}
```

and then add this to your app delegate's `didFinishLaunchWithOptions` method to tie it all up.

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
} else {
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 4.1

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in
        self.getNotificationSettings()
    })

} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```